# In django, how can I filter or exclude multiple things?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

If I have this queryset:

```
player = basketball.objects.all()
```

How can I do a filter where I ask for multiple people? For example: I only want players who's names are "mike" or "charles" to show up. This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
player.filter(name = 'mike' , 'charles')
```

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
player.filter(name__in=['mike', 'charles'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Alongside the use of `__in`, you can also chain multiple filters using the [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q), so `objects.filter(q)` where `q = Q(Q(name="mike")|Q(name="phil"))`.

Definitely use `__in` though in this case.